# SQL Error 1054 Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

I've created an database with 5 tables and each of the tables have various rows and columns as data.

When I try to select some of that data, I'm getting that error in the title and I have no idea how to do it otherwise!!

Here's the thing:

```
Tables_in_table01
Afdeling
Apparaat
Leverancier
Medewerkers
Onderhoud
```

Those are the tables my database consist of and these are the definitions:

```
Afdeling =      AfdelingNR + AfdelingNaam + Medewerkers_MedewerkerNR 

Leverancier =   LeverancierNR + Naam + Contactpersoon + Adres + Telefoon + Email

Apparaat =      ApparaatNR + AfdelingNR + Aanschafdatum + Leverancier_LeverancierNR + Onderhoudtermijn + Afschrijvingsdatum

Medewerkers =   MedewerkerNR + Geslacht + Functie + Voorletters + Tussenvoegsel + Achternaam + Beeper

Onderhoud =     OnderhoudNR + Medewerker_MedewerkerNR + Apparaat_ApparaatNR
```

When I try to select the following:

```
SELECT MedewerkerNR, Voorletters, Tussenvoegsel, Achternaam
FROM Medewerkers
WHERE Medewerkers.MedewerkerNR=Afdeling.Medewerkers_MedewerkerNR
AND Afdeling.AfdelingNR=Apparaat.AfdelingNR;
```

It says:

> Error 1054 (42S22): Unknown column
>   'Afdeling.Medewerkers_MedwerkerNR' in 'where clause'

Why is this column unknown? I've checked it and the data does exist in the table..

After using `SHOW CREATE TABLE Afdeling;` 
I've gotten the following:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE Afdeling;
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Create Table


                                                      |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------+
| Afdeling | CREATE TABLE `afdeling` (
  `AfdelingNR` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `AfdelingNaam` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Medewerkers_MedewerkerNR` decimal(8,0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AfdelingNR`),
  KEY `Afdeling_FKIndex1` (`Medewerkers_MedewerkerNR`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Any help is greatly accepted!

Cheers!

Comment: Could you please run SHOW CREATE TABLE Afdeling (&c...)?

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910652/error-1054-42s22-unknown-column-in-field-list - similar sort of error relating to unknown (potentially invisible chars in query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only included the Medewerkers table in your query, and not the Afdeling or Apparaat table.

try this:

```
SELECT MedewerkerNR, Voorletters, Tussenvoegsel, Achternaam
FROM Medewerkers, Afdeling, Apparaat
WHERE Medewerkers.MedewerkerNR=Afdeling.Medewerkers_MedewerkerNR
AND Afdeling.AfdelingNR=Apparaat.AfdelingNR;
```

or better yet, try this:

```
SELECT MedewerkerNR, Voorletters, Tussenvoegsel, Achternaam
FROM Medewerkers
INNER JOIN 
Afdeling
ON Medewerkers.MedewerkerNR=Afdeling.Medewerkers_MedewerkerNR
INNER JOIN Apparaat    
ON Afdeling.AfdelingNR=Apparaat.AfdelingNR;
```

Comment: Oh god.. Thanks alot for this.. I should've known this >_> Guess it's time for a break!